# Como mover uma UITextField em Xamarin.ios?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

Eu queria mover uma `UITextField` para cima ou para baixo de forma a resolver o problema do '**keyboard**'

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

tentei desta forma

```
 TextChaveAcesso.Frame.Location = new CoreGraphics.CGPoint(TextChaveAcesso.Frame.Y, TextChaveAcesso.Frame.Y);
```